# Jquery Modal Popup to show in center of screen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following jquery code to open a modal popup on click on an Action in MVC 3.

**Action**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change", "Settings", "Account", null, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "newPostDialog", data_dialog_title = "Change" })
```

**Jquery**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this)
                .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    modal: true,
                    width:1020

                })
                .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
```

**Problem**

I am not able to position my modal popup in the center of the screen or align it with the top of the screen.

I have tried this, but doesnt work.

```
dialog({
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            close: function () { $(this).remove() },
            modal: true,
            width:1020,
            top:0,
            left:10


        })
```

Being a naive in jquery I am unable to find a solution to this. Can anyone please guide me in geting this.

A default style of `style=display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 1020px; top: 394px; left: 439px;` is added automaically, I just want to change `top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strangely adding a `height` value did the trick, here is what I have used

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this)
            .attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                modal: true,
                height:860,
                width:900,
                left:0

            })
            .load(this.href);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, two reasons why the centering wasn't working for me...

first time around I didn't include the position javascript library/class, so even though all the code was right, I had to set the height manually until I realized that the `jquery.ui.position` was missing

after I got that sorted out, it was centering properly, but the page was acting out and I couldn't see the modal, what happened was that my link redirecting the page to itself and scrolling up, adding `return false;` at the end of the `dialog{}` function solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to position it after opening.

```
dialog({
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            close: function () { $(this).remove() },
            open: function () {$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", "center" );},
            modal: true,
            width:1020,
            top:0,
            left:10


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a little bit of CSS.

Let's assume the structure of your HTML is something like the following:

`<div id="modal-container"><div id="modal-dialog"></div></div>`

```
#modal-container { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#modal-dialog { width: 1020px; margin: auto; }
```

In essence, you just want a container with `position: fixed` just below the root of the HTML document body. This way, the container's width and height will be equal to the window width and height. Inside that, setting the width and `margin: auto` of the dialog box will ensure that it is centered horizontally, since it is auto-setting its margins based on the width of the entire window.

Comment: my main div is automatically adding this `style=display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 1020px; top: 394px; left: 439px;`, so any style I give is overridden

Answer (score 0):

Yasser,

just two properties missing I'm certain:

```
.dialog({
    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
    close: function() { $(this).remove() },
    modal: true,
    width: 1020,
    height: 800,
    position: 'center'
});
```

should work I reckon.

Comment: hey @jim I already got this working see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11717427/1182982) Thanks !

Comment: doh - just saw that, no worries :-)